# Elastic Search JPA Repository not providing result for findAll and findBy... methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch for crud operations in elastic-search.

Only able to save data to elastic-search and findById method is working.

findAll and findBy... method is not working, and giving empty response.

I tried with some other versions in POM

After some debugging i found that findById method is actually sending a HTTP GET request, and findAll/findBy... is sending HTTP POST request.

In both the cases GET/POST elastic-search is returning the response with data, that i verified on wireshark. which was running on local. 
I can see the hits in response of findAll method call, on wireshark but that hits we i am not receiving via repository.

If i can see the response with data, that means elastic-search and query creation is fine, but the problem is with consuming the data in JPA. JPA is actually handling the consumption thing.

I don't have any idea about how to debug further.

Data Model Class

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Document(indexName = "data", type = "_doc")
    public class Data {

        @Id
        private String id;

        private String title;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
        private Status status;

        private String description;
    }
```

Repository Class

```
    @Repository
    public interface DataRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Data,String> {
        default <S extends Data> S saveWithKafkaPush(S s){
            S s1 = save(s);
            KafkaProducer.produceMessage(s);
            return s1;
        }

        default <S extends Data> Iterable<S> saveAllWithKafkaPush(Iterable<S> iterable){
            Iterable<S> s = saveAll(iterable);
            return s;
        }

        Optional<Data> findByStatus(Status status);
    }
```

Status Enum

```
    public enum Status {
        UNTITLED,
        DRAFT,
        REVIEW,
        APPROVED,
        PUBLISHED;
    }
```

Service Class

```
    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    public Data findByStatus(Status status){
        Optional<Data> data = dataRepository.findByStatus(status);
        return data.isPresent()? data.get() : null;
    }

    public Data save(Data data){
        return dataRepository.save(data);
    }

    public void deleteData(String id){
        dataRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

findByStatus method is not working but save and deleteData is working fine.

Comment: which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch itself are you using? And how relates this to JPA?